# getAllCellInfo() and getAllCellInfo() returns null in android oreo

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

I tried both of these methods getAllCellInfo() and getCellLocation() for getting Location Area Code,Cell ID and Primary Scrambling Code in Android Oreo . But these methods return null (the app minimised and background service is always running) . So, what can I do to get the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getAllCellInfo() and getAllCellInfo() returns null on Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56162850/getallcellinfo-and-getallcellinfo-returns-null-on-oreo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getAllCellInfo() returns empty list in honor 9n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376732/getallcellinfo-returns-empty-list-in-honor-9n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telephony information now relies on device location setting

If the user has disabled device location on a device running Android 9, the following methods don't provide results:

```
    getAllCellInfo()

    listen()

    getCellLocation()

    getNeighboringCellInfo()
```