# getAllCellInfo() returns empty list in honor 9n

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

`getAllCellInfo()` returns empty list in `honor 9n`. I am used for to get Cell id and Location area code. So what will i do to get Cell id and Location area code.

I also tried `getCellLocation()`. And I got Cell id and Location area code when `GPS` is on. I want to get Cell id and Location area code when the `GPS` is in off state.(OS Android Oreo).

```
TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);                                                                        

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }                                                  

    CellLocation gsmCellLocation1 = tel.getCellLocation();
    if(gsmCellLocation1!=null){
        Log.e("gsmCellLocation1: ", String.valueOf(gsmCellLocation1));
    }else{
        Log.e("gsmCellLocation1: ", "nul 1");

    }                      

    GsmCellLocation location33 = (GsmCellLocation) tel.getCellLocation();
    if(location33!=null){
        Log.e("location33: ", String.valueOf(location33));
    }else{
        Log.e("location33: ", "nul 33");

    }

    final List<CellInfo> gsmCellLocation2 = tel.getAllCellInfo();
    if(gsmCellLocation2!=null){
        Log.e("gsmCellLocation2: ", String.valueOf(gsmCellLocation2));
    }else{
        Log.e("gsmCellLocation2: ", "nul 2");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user has disabled device location on a device running Android 9, the following methods don't provide results:

```
getAllCellInfo()
listen()
getCellLocation()
getNeighboringCellInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

and use this instead of `getCellLocation().`

```
getNeighboringCellInfo()
```

Comment: I already using that permission and I already tried  getNeighboringCellInfo() it also retuns empty list

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, my code worked in devices with Android version less than 9. When the device location is disabled, the getAllCellInfo() returns an empty list in the Android 9 device that I am testing upon. When the device location is turned on, things work fine.